# Show data from USB to eink bonnet

Tags: pi-3b+, serial, gps, adafruit, eink

So I have a RPI with a adafruit 2.13 eink bonnet installed onto my GPIO pins. Then I have a gearmo USB-RS232 serial converter plugged into my USB port then the RS232 connection is on a GPS receiver. I am wanting to have the eink display how many satellites the receiver is currently tracking on the eink.

Is there a way for me to take the data coming in via USB on my rpi and redirect it to the GPIO pins and display the information I am wanting on my eink bonnet?

Comment: yes there is ... you can do almost anything on a linux computer

Answer (score 1):

How much programming do you want to do? There will be some involved. Also, how pretty do you want it to be? The nicer displays look, the more work required.

Whatever you do, there are two main tasks:

1. get the number of satellites from the GPS
2. display that number on the e-ink screen.

#### 1. get the number of satellites from the GPS

There are a couple of ways of doing this:

- read the low-level [NMEA sentences](http://aprs.gids.nl/nmea/) from the GPS serial port (`/dev/ttyUSB0`, typically), parse them (for example, using the [pynmea2](https://github.com/Knio/pynmea2) Python 3 library: `sudo apt install python3-nmea2`) and extract the *num_sats* field from the CGA sentences
- install and configure [gpsd](https://gpsd.gitlab.io/gpsd/) (`sudo apt install gpsd gpsd-clients`) then run a client (in Python 3, perhaps based on [MartijnBraam/gpsd-py3: Python 3 GPSD client](https://github.com/MartijnBraam/gpsd-py3)) that extracts the number field.

gpsd is perhaps preferable, as it allows more than one program to access GPS information.

#### 2. display that number on the e-ink screen

This depends on what model of screen you have. Adafruit have updated and changed variants over time, but I'll assume it's this: [Adafruit 2.13" Monochrome E-Ink Bonnet for Raspberry Pi - THINK INK](https://www.adafruit.com/product/4687). Adafruit provides a Python 3 library plus lengthy [example tutorials](https://learn.adafruit.com/raspberry-pi-e-ink-weather-station-using-python) with examples: [adafruit/Adafruit_CircuitPython_EPD: e paper driver for circuit python](https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_CircuitPython_EPD).

Link-only examples are frowned upon here, but without having a GPS or the same e-ink screen as you, providing a working example would be impractical for me. The basic program flow might be

```
# import all the necessary Adafruit CircuitPython compatibility libraries
# import the gpsd library
import time

# let's assume there's lots of magic code in here that sets up two objects
# 1. display - the interface to the e-ink screen
# 2. gpsd    - the interface to the gpsd daemon

while True:
    sat_count = str(gpsd.sats)                        # get number of satellites seen
    display.fill(Adafruit_EPD.WHITE)                  # clear screen
    display.text(sat_count, 5, 5, Adafruit_EPD.BLACK) # draw your text
    display.display()                                 # update screen
    time.sleep(30)
```

This might produce an extremely tedious display (something like the number 14 in a dull tiny bitmap font near the top left of your screen) but it would be showing the number, as per your question. There are nice things you can do with TrueType fonts to make pretty displays, as described in the [weather](https://learn.adafruit.com/raspberry-pi-e-ink-weather-station-using-python/overview) example.

Don't try to to update e-ink/EP displays too often. Not merely are they slow to update, but their pixels are tiny electromechanical things. In theory, they wear out eventually, but technology might have improved their life somewhat. I had an older screen [fail](https://forums.pimoroni.com/t/streaky-inkyphat/5201/81) after about a week of updates every 30 seconds.